# "No Application Access Policy found for this App"

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

"No Application Access Policy found for this App" error in PowerAutomate-HTTP Action Card

I Got all permissions from both Azure and MicrosoftGraphDesigner-API
I also Create an App in AzureActiveDirectory
Collect my user,App,Object,client,secret,Tenant Ids From my Active directory App
And also I run Access cs commands in powershell by My Admin
But Still now I got the Same no Application Access policy error in PowerAutomate
Why still its Continue ?

Experts please solve My issue
I am fresher in Azure & powerShell
some information are not understand by me
Any Experts please Give Solutions
connecting in Teams meeting will be of Great help to me

Thanks & Regards
Your help is greatly Anticipated
HARIHARAN.A

Comment: The following configuration needs to be performed : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy#configure-application-access-policy

Answer (score 1):

The error "***No Application Access Policy found for this App***" usually occurs if the application doesn't have required permissions/access to perform the action.

To resolve the error, try creating Application access policy like below:

```bash
Connect-ExchangeOnline

New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AccessRight Access -AppId "xxx" -PolicyScopeGroupId "xxx" -Description "xxx"
Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity  xxx -AppId xxx
```

[image]

You can test the policy by using `Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity  xxx -AppId ClientID`

**Otherwise**, I agree with @*jdweng*, you can create policy by using below commands refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy#configure-application-access-policy):

```bash
New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Test-policy -AppIds "xxxx" -Description "test"

Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName Test-policy -Identity "xxx"
```

**If still the issue persists**, check the below:

- Check whether the Azure AD Application have required permissions to access the resource.
- Make sure you are passing correct values of `Client_ID`, `Tenant_ID`, `Client_Secret`.
- Otherwise create a new application and try.

**References:**

[Configure an application access policy using the cloud communications API - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy#configure-application-access-policy)

[New-ApplicationAccessPolicy (ExchangePowerShell)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps)